# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use tensorflow to build my own neural network and run it, I meet a very strange error. The error is that

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape
>   mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [400], got [3200].

I have no idea about how [3200] comes, could anyone can help to fix this problem? The input of the neural network is a 400-dimension vector.

[Here is one part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X3IL.png)
[Here is one part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJXVR.png)
[Here is one part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hvcd.png)
[Here is one part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svJmb.png)
Here is the output
[output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrJMJ.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6HJE.png)
[output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWSP2.png)

Comment: Is your `batch_size` 8 by any chance?

Comment: provide the the print outputs you get

Comment: No,my batch size is 100

Comment: first of all you are not reading any data, your batch is empty